# Less than sign (<) and Greater than sign (>) are not the same size or shape in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unicode, textview

When I try to add special characters in android studio TextView, the less than sign is not the same size/shape as greater than sign. Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaRiJ.png) so you know what I am talking about.

I used these characters in my strings.xml file:

```
<string name="mainPageText">See all available rooms \u003E</string>
<string name="listPageText">\uFE64 See my current status</string>
```

Is there any way to fix it so that they are both the same size and shape ?

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe64/index.htm and https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3e/index.htm - one is a "SMALL LESS-THAN SIGN", the other is a "GREATER-THAN SIGN". You need to simply choose the correct unicode characters.

Comment: Oh my god. Such a stupid mistake. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+003C < and
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+003E >

or

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FE64 ﹤ and
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FE65 ﹥

instead of mixing one from the first and one from the second

(the difference is not as visible on SO due to a different font)